# Which OS for a 2GB RAM MacBook Air from 2011?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, memory

My Macbook Air from mid 2011 has 2 GB RAM, its processor is 1.6 GHz i5, 64 GB of flash storage. Its OS is the one it had originally, Lion.

Many apps require to upgrade the OS - e.g Slack. Yet I don't think going for Sierra with 2 GB RAM is a good idea, and I can't upgrade the RAM as it is impossible on new Macbook Airs.

Which OS would my MBA handle, would Yosemite or Mavericks be manageable for it ?

Comment: Mine has the same specs as yours and is running Sierra fine and well.
I'm still thinking about running High Sierra on it but I guess it can't handle it.... only 2gb of ram...

Comment: Have you tried [macOS High Sierra Patcher?](http://dosdude1.com/highsierra/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will take Sierra - which means unless you already have any earlier OS in your App Store purchase history, that's the only one you can get for it.

Source: [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i5-1.6-13-early-2012-edu-specs.html)

Comment: Yet isn't it possible to buy an earlier OS even though I have not downloaded it at the time ? [example with snow leopard](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard?fnode=5b701bb99b0cc47453ef960eaec9e9fccc4f68420626d2acc467419829babc1294eeb91b7c6b1ae5da89ffaf54b0a3c45c1372428f4926365c044278714273ed9ea42624cb7e71945954391e912f7a988b24d02d982e4737e8d0b4e52a0fc427)

Comment: Apple haven't sold an OS for money since Lion 10.7 [which is what that machine came with originally] & even then was really not much more than the cost of the CD it was supplied on. Everything since Mountain Lion 10.8 is supplied through the App Store only, & belongs to the Apple ID that 'bought' it through there [even though it didn't cost money]. The only way to get anything older than 'current' is to have already 'bought' it, so it's in your App Store purchase history.

Comment: You said, "_Apple haven't sold an OS for money since Lion 10.7_" and that is not correct as Apple sold OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, I know because I paid for it! OS X 10.9 Mavericks was the first free version of OS X.

Comment: Close, even if no cigar - though that wasn't really the point I was trying to make.